# Unfair Three-Sided die

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Say you have an unfair 3-sided die.
>
> Side 1 will be rolled with probability $p_1$.
>
> Side 2 will be rolled with probability $p_2$.
>
> Side 3 will be rolled with probability $p_3$.
>
> Find a formula for the probability that the 8th 3 will be rolled on the 10th roll.

My theory on this is to use a binomial distribution, but I am pretty lost.
Could anyone with more experience in probability help me out with this? I was just trying to work through a book I had and I want to figure this out.

Edit: Using Robert's advice this is the direction I'm going:

$9\choose 7$$(p_3)^7$$(1-p_3)^2*p_3$

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. There are $\binom{9}{7}$ ways to distribute the seven $3$s rolled before the $10$th roll. The probability to get a $3$ is $p_3$. The probability to get a different number is $1-p_3$.

Please edit your question and write your attempt.

Comment: I edited my question based on your advice... am I going in the right direction?

Comment: @pistachioparlor That's right! Note that this is a variant of the negative binomial distribution.

Comment: @batman It is correct. Well done!